# Reading a folder of csv files with specific name endings followed by filtering with dplyr and combining output into single dataframe

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a folder containing 13000 csv files.

**Problem 1:** I need to read all the files ending with -postings.csv. All the -postings.csv files have same number of variables and same format.

So far I have the following

```
name_post = list.files(pattern="-postings.csv")
for (i in 1:length(name_post)) assign(name_post[i], read.csv(name_post[i], header=TRUE))
```

This creates around 600 dataframes.

**Problem 2:** I need to filter the 600 dataframe output trough the following rules

1) column_name1 != "" (remove all empty rows)

2) column_name2 ==124 (only keep rows with values equal to 124)

So far I have only done this on a single file, but need a way to get this done on all 600 dataframes. (I use filter which is part of the dplyr package. I am open for other solutions)
    filter(`random_name-postings.csv`,column_name1 != "",column_name2==124)

**Problem 3:** I need to combine the filtering output from problem 2 into a single dataframe.

I have not done this since I have issues solving problem 2.

Any help is much appreciated :)

Comment: I'd create a list out of the csv files, then you can rbind them and do your operations.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rather than working with the data frames as 600 separate variables, which isn't a good idea, you can combine them into one data frame as soon as you read them in. `map_df` from the purrr package is a good way to do this.

```
library(purrr)

name_post = list.files(pattern="-postings.csv")
combined = map_df(name_post, read.csv, header = TRUE)
```

After that, you can perform your filtering on the combined dataset.

```
library(dplyr)
combined_filtered = combined %>%
  filter(column_name1 != "", column_name2 == 124)
```

---

Note that if you want to know which file each row originally came from, you could turn `name_post` into a named vector and use `.id = "filename"`, which would add a `filename` column to your output.

```
names(name_post) = name_post
combined = map_df(name_post, read.csv, header = TRUE, .id = "filename")
```

Comment: You are a legend Patronus! :)